# Streaming live camera video from iOS (iPhone/iPad) to remote PC / server

Tags: ios, objective-c, video-streaming, avfoundation, rtmp

I've been searching for a while on stackoverflow and around the web for a solution to my video-streaming problem. I need to stream live video being captured from the camera (no high-quality required) from an iOS device to a remote PC in one way, i.e., the iOS device will be sending a video stream to the server/PC but not the opposite.

What appears after some googling and documentation browsing is that there are two main major standards/protocols that can be used:

- Apple's HTTP Live Streaming (HLS)
- Adobe's RTMP

Again, my requirement is that the iPhone/iPad will be streaming the video. From what appears on Apple's website, I understand that HLS is to be used from an encoding perspective server-side, and a decoding perspective iOS side. As of RTMP, most libraries that allow iOS streaming have commercial licenses and closed code or require you to go through their P2P infrastructure (for instance [angl.tv](http://angl.tv/) or [tokbox.com/opentok/quick-start](http://tokbox.com/opentok/quick-start/)). As of HLS, no encoding libraries seem to exist iOS side.

So my questions are:

- Do you know of any SDK/Library preferably open and free that I could integrate to stream captured video from within my app?
- If no, do you think developing a custom library would be a risky jungle-crossing endeavour? My guess is to go through AVFoundation and capture camera frames, compress them frame by frame and send them over HTTP. Does that sound crazy performance and bandwidth wise? Note that in that case I would need an HLS or RTMP encoder either ways.

I thank you very much in advance dear friends.

Mehdi.

Comment: It might be a lot more than what you need, but [webrtc](http://www.webrtc.org/) can do this (it's actually for cross-platform video calling without any plugins). It takes some time to set everything up, but if you want to expand your functionality later on this could be a good solution.

Answer (score 29):

I have developed such a library, and you can find it at [github.com/jgh-/VideoCore](http://github.com/jgh-/VideoCore)

I am updating this answer because I have created a simplified iOS API that will allow you to easily setup a Camera/Mic RTMP session.  You can find it at https://github.com/jgh-/VideoCore/blob/master/api/iOS/VCSimpleSession.h.

Additionally, VideoCore is now available in CocoaPods.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for this library. Interesting work. Any plans to wrap it in Cocoa Touch/Objective-C library?

Comment: @MediTheJedi I have added a sample iOS project to VideoCore to demonstrate streaming to an RTMP server with the camera and microphone.  Find it at https://github.com/jamesghurley/VideoCore/tree/master/sample

Comment: Is there any URL where we can see the posted videos from iOS devices.

Comment: You need to have an RTMP server available.  Note that this can also connect to services such as Justin.tv where you are given a stream key and ingest server url.

Comment: I am getting error in VideoCore library that file not found while all files are included in project. i have checked the path also.Please help

Comment: Please email me using the address found in the readme or open an issue. Be sure to include your errors and header search paths in the issue or email

Comment: This library give throwing this error:
#include <UriParser/UriParser.hpp>
file not found .

Comment: Hi Jamesghurley, I have gone through your VideoCore sample iOS project. Can you give me some inputs on what we have to do for HTTP steaming instead of RTMP. Which approach is better like opening a websocked and sending what ever we get after encoding or transfer MPEG-2 stream, how can we built a MPEG-2 stream from encoded cmsamplebuffers?

Comment: @jgh is it possible to stream with your lib to youtube?

Comment: It works! But sample only for output stream from camera, does this library play rtmp stream from server?

Comment: Does this swift code will broadcast live video to my RTMP server from my iPhone?

Comment: Hi @jgh.. i tried the sample app. I have included my RTMP server address with key, its giving me the below error

ClientState: 2
ClientState: 3
ClientState: 4
ClientState: 5
ClientState: 6
received server window size: 2500000
received peer bandwidth limit: 2500000 type: 2
Request to change incoming chunk size from 128 -> 4096
Received invoke
pktId: 1
received invoke _result
tracked command: connect
ClientState: 7
Received invoke
pktId: 0
received invoke onBWDone
ClientState: 11

Comment: @ Sanjay Kumar Yadav Yes you are right. I noticed the same issue

Comment: Can anyone share some sample code for live video streaming in Swift pls?